# Item Updating list item event receiver on Person or Group field (Multi-User field)

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, event-receiver, eventreceiver

My requirement is to get all the users from the sharepoint list item (person or group field) and assign [Read] permissions to different document libraries. As it has multiple users, on list item update, **Is it possible to compare the before and after properties of person or Group field and add/remove permissions of the newly added/removed user?**

Currently on item update, I am removing all the existing user permissions and adding them back on item update. I don't even know whether the person or group field has been modified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test if your column have changed during the `ItemUpdating` event. Inside `SPItemEventProperties` you can find Property called `AfterProperties`.
When working on the `ItemUpdating` you can use `BeforeProperties` or just use `properties.ListItem` both of them store the original value.

So if you want to test if anything has changed inside your column you might use following code:

```
if (properties.ListItem["customColumn"] != properties.AfterProperties["customColumn"])
{
}
```

But since you have the multi-value user field this won't wokr because these collections return generic objects, which you will have to convert to something comparable (for example by using `ToString()` method).

Try something following:

```
 if(properties.ListItem["column"]?.ToString() != properties.AfterProperties["column"]?.ToString()) 
 {
 }
```

Let me know if that helps.